# CNN not performing well on a random image despite having very good accuracy in training and testing

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, face-recognition

```
enter code here
from tensorflow import keras


classifier = keras.Sequential()

classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(16,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape = (64,64,3),activation = 
'relu'))

classifier.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(32,kernel_size=(3, 3),activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
#classifier.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(64,kernel_size=(3, 3),activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
classifier.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Dense( 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(r'C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\Deep Learning\dataset2\Training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 8,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(r'C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\Deep Learning\dataset2\Test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 8,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch =2140,
                         epochs = 30,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 90)

import numpy as np
from keras_preprocessing import image
test_image=image.load_img(r'D:\IDM DOWNLOADS\Data Set A-Z DL\Convolutional_Neural_Networks\dataset\single_prediction\shifaface6.jpg',target_size=(64,64))
test_image=image.array_to_img(test_image)
test_image=np.expand_dims(test_image,axis=0)
result=classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0]==1:
    prediction='Shifa'
else:
    prediction='Rishav'
```

After Training and Testing I get accuracy close to 100% in both test and train set ,but when I give image 
of Shifa it still classifies it as Rishav,and Rishav's image is classified as Rishav.My dataset contains 1070 images for each class for training and 45 images for testing in each class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to rescale the pixel range of your new image by dividing it by 255

Comment: How do I do that on a single image?

Comment: if `test_image` is an array this would work `image.array_to_img(test_image/255)`

Comment: I divided the image by 255 but still, the same problem exists.